# Two references with Entity Framework models conflict

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, edmx

I am trying to implement a utility which references two already existing legacy console applications. Both of them use Entity Framework and have a model of a particular table defined, for example `Table1`.

Both utilities work perfectly as stand-alone applications. However, when both are being included in another project, one runs fine and the other throws an error when trying to save changes in the context:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.MetadataException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Additional information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

Table1DataModel.ssdl(3,4) : error 0019:
The EntityContainer name must be unique.
An EntityContainer with the name 'Table1ModelStoreContainer' is already defined.
```

There actually is a `Table1ModelStoreContainer` in the `.edmx` file in both projects.

Is there a way to make them work together without modifying the source code of existing tools?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with references. Check references to Entity Framework in both projects. Also look up configuration files (app.config), are there correct references to EF.

Comment: Both utilities work when I call them independently. It only crashes within my new utility, because both have the same database referenced under the same name. Existing applications cannot be altered, therefore I'm looking for a solution on the side of the application that glues them together.

Comment: @Impworks did you try to change the name of entity container? In situation you describe and error 0019 you can guess that names of your entity containers are the same. Open Model Browser, there is node "EntityContainer: YourName". If there are the same for both model, change one of them and try to blast off your app. :)

Comment: that's the point. The names **are** the same, hence the error, but they are defined in existing applications that I cannot modify in any way. I just have the two .exe files which I add as project references and then create an instance of the main class defined in each of them.

Comment: Okay, so I'll wait for the answer with you. It doesn't seem simple. Consider bounty. :)